# C# select ids from list

Tags: c#, list

I like to know if there is a better way to select the Ids in a list object than use a for each loop and a string builder.

```
   class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Person> peopleList = new List<Person>();
        peopleList.Add(new Person() { ID = 1 });
        peopleList.Add(new Person() { ID = 2 });
        peopleList.Add(new Person() { ID = 3 });

        //string Ids = peopleList.Select(x => x.ID);
        StringBuilder Ids = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var people in peopleList)
        {
            Ids.Append(people.ID);
            Ids.Append("-");
        }

        Console.WriteLine(Ids.ToString());
    }



    class Person
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `string.Join("-", peopleList.Select(p => p.ID));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8) and [Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8):

```
string.Join("-", peopleList.Select(x => x.ID))
```

[Try it Online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EDf2tD)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Person> peopleList = new List<Person>();
    peopleList.Add(new Person() { ID = 1 });
    peopleList.Add(new Person() { ID = 2 });
    peopleList.Add(new Person() { ID = 3 });


    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("-", peopleList.Select(x => x.ID)));
}

class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Learning Linq & Lambda Expressions makes life a bit easier...